# Creating a Tic Tac Toe app, I have this bug where it declares a draw every single time on the same square

Tags: java, android, tic-tac-toe

So I have this bug that whenever I click the top left square, regardless of whether it's at the very beginning of the game or in the middle or whenever, I always get the draw message for the game and I can continue playing the game.

[Picture of "Draw Bug"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nEZ4h.png)

Other than that, the game works fine. I have tried creating different logic but it just doesn't seem to control that bug. Can someone please tell me where I'm wrong? I'll attach my code.

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.media.Image;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.GridLayout;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

int activePlayer = 0; //0 = Yellow; 1 = Red
boolean gameIsActive = true;

int[] gameState = {2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2}; // 2 = unplayed.
int[][] winningPositions = {‌{0,1,2}, {3,4,5}, {6,7,8}, {0,3,6}, {1,4,7}, {2,5,8}, {0,4,8}, {2,4,6}};

public void dropIn(View view) {

    ImageView counter = (ImageView) view;

    int tappedCounter = Integer.parseInt(counter.getTag().toString());

    if (gameState[tappedCounter] == 2 && gameIsActive) {

        gameState[tappedCounter] = activePlayer;
        counter.setTranslationY(-1500f);
        if (activePlayer == 0) {
            counter.setImageResource(R.drawable.yellow);
            activePlayer = 1;
        } else {
            counter.setImageResource(R.drawable.red);
            activePlayer = 0;
        }

        counter.animate().translationYBy(1500f).rotation(360).setDuration(600);

        for (int[] winningPosition : winningPositions){
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(gameState));
            if (gameState[winningPosition[0]] == gameState[winningPosition[1]] &&
                    gameState[winningPosition[1]] == gameState[winningPosition[2]] &&
                    gameState[winningPosition[0]] != 2){

                //Someone has won

                gameIsActive = false;
                String winner = "Red";

                if (gameState[winningPosition[0]] == 0){
                    winner = "Yellow";
                }

                TextView winnerMessage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.winnerMessage);
                winnerMessage.setText(winner + " has won!");
                final LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.playAgainLayout);
                layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            // there is a draw

            else {

                boolean gameIsOver = true;

                for (int counterState : gameState) {

                    if (counterState == 2)
                        gameIsOver = false;

                    if(gameIsOver){
                        TextView winnerMessage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.winnerMessage);
                        winnerMessage.setText("It's a draw. ");
                        final LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.playAgainLayout);
                        layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

public void playAgain(View view){

    gameIsActive = true;

    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.playAgainLayout);
    layout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    activePlayer = 0; //0 = Yellow; 1 = Red

    for (int i = 0; i < gameState.length; i++){
        gameState[i] = 2;
    }

    androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout gridLayout = findViewById(R.id.gridLayout);

    for (int i = 0; i < gridLayout.getChildCount(); i++){
        ((ImageView) gridLayout.getChildAt(i)).setImageResource(0);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

}
}
```

Comment: Look at your `for (int[] winningPosition : winningPositions){}` loop: 1) You're checking a bunch of conditions,  2) if they're not all "true", then 3) you immediately fall into the "else" block, set "game over" and call it a "draw" ;) Whoops ;)

Comment: @paulsm4 Wouldn't this mean that it would register a draw upon clicking any square rather than very particular square? Because I added a log to display what the state of each square is upon playing it and all of the conditions are valid so as to continue playing.